# wordpress error on line 160 of ...wp-includes\class-wp-customize-control.php whilst adding hooks for extra functions

Tags: wordpress, hook, customization, member-functions

**Thanks in advance for any help with this**,
Error Call to a member function check_capabilities()

stuck in a rut with this one!

Directory layout:

- 'Theme folder'

  - functions.php (main directory for 'Theme')
  - index.php
  - style.css
  - functions folder (located inside of 'Theme folder')

    - customize.php

Functions calls customize.php like this:

```
<?php require_once('functions/customize.php'); ?>
```

customize.php:

```
<?php
add_action('customize_register', 'adaptive_customize_register');
function adaptive_customize_register($wp_customize) {
//logo
$wp_customize->add_section('adaptive_logo', array(
'title' => __('Add Logo', 'adaptive_framework'), 
'description' => __('Upload your main logo, this shows in the header',      'adaptive_framework'), 
'priority' => '25'
));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('adaptive_custom_settings[add_logo]', array(
    'default' => 0,
    'type' => 'option'
));

$wp_customize->add_control('adaptive_custom_settings[display_logo]', array(
    'label' => __('Display logo?','adaptive_framework'),
    'section' => 'adaptive_logo',
    'settings' => 'adaptive_custom_settings[display_top_logo]',
    'type' => 'checkbox'
    ));
}



?>
```

If anyone can help with please as I get error as follows:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function check_capabilities() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-customize-control.php on line 160
```

Comment: `$cutomize` or `$customize`?

Comment: @brasofilo - I appreciate I made a typo but the error remains the same I have checked through for typos and still returning the error on line 160

Comment: Hard one to debug :/ .... I don't understand what capability it is expecting nor where should we put it. The [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control) is not very complete. Maybe [this article](http://ottopress.com/2012/making-a-custom-control-for-the-theme-customizer/) (linked in the docs) can help.

Comment: Not many results, but worth a look: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=WP_Customize_Control

Comment: I've re-written the whole thing seems to have figured it out - however bummer is I've deleted it accidentally.

Comment: Gee, man... use a good IDE, NetBeans keeps a history of the code modifications ;)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Had to end this thread as the code I'm using is now no longer required, I will look to get the finished code as working in an example online.

Answer (score 6):

The settings parameter of add_control() has to match the name of the setting defined in add_setting(). Otherwise the control is added to an unknown setting which causes the capabilities error.

Therefore change `adaptive_custom_settings[display_top_logo]` to `adaptive_custom_settings[add_logo]`

```
    <?php
    add_action('customize_register', 'adaptive_customize_register');
    function adaptive_customize_register($wp_customize) {
    //logo
    $wp_customize->add_section('adaptive_logo', array(
        'title' => __('Add Logo', 'adaptive_framework'), 
        'description' => __('Upload your main logo, this shows in the header',         'adaptive_framework'), 
        'priority' => '25'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('adaptive_custom_settings[add_logo]', array(
        'default' => 0,
        'type' => 'option'
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control('adaptive_custom_settings[display_logo]', array(
        'label' => __('Display logo?','adaptive_framework'),
        'section' => 'adaptive_logo',
        'settings' => 'adaptive_custom_settings[add_logo]',
        'type' => 'checkbox'
    ));
    }
    ?>
```